# SSH, execute commands as yourself

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, terminal

In ssh, I have often wondered if there is any way to execute commands that affect your own account rather than the one you are logged in to, or do you have to log out every time and/or open a new tab?

I wonder because often times i would like to cp a file from the target account to my own or something similar.

The closest I know right now is something like

```
cat file.txt | pbcopy
# exit ssh
pbpaste > file.txt
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
cat file.txt | ssh user@localhost 'cat > file.txt'
```

may have some advantages in some cases. For example you can use auto-login.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer files from/to remote machine, you can try [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp):

```
scp [[user@]host1:]file1 [[user@]host2:]file2
```